# Share current SAP with new SFMC instance which is on different stack

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sender-authentication-package

We are in the process of moving our brand to a new SFMC instance. Our old instance which is running as of now is on stack 10 while the new one that we got is on s11. Does this mean SAP cannot be shared with the new instance?

We plan to move to new instance completely and then go live with it meanwhile disabling the old instance. So what are our options here? I read some answers related to this and understood that the best thing to do would be to get a new domain and do IP Warming and then start using that domain. But in our scenario, we do not have scope for a new domain and IP Warming process.

Can someone share their experience and best practices in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SAP can not be shared across stacks. Specifically sending IPs can not move between instances on different stacks. Also, a full SAP has some DNS records that are stack specific - which also means your current SAP is tied to stack 10.

Your only option is to plan and initiate an IP warmup process, with a new IP and SAP domain, sending from stack 11.

Comment: Thanks Lukas! We have asked Salesforce Support to give us an instance on stack 10. If we get that, we can go ahead with sharing the same SAP and no IP Warming will be needed, right? And are there any red flags we need to consider in sharing the SAP with the new instance?

Comment: Correct - if your two instances are on same stack, you shouldn't experience any problems, and sharing an SAP between EIDs poses no risks.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Lukas!